Used statistics from XML plan cache for query with given QueryPlanHash
I'm using SQL Server 2016/2019. I want to extract (for given @QueryPlanHash BINARY(8) = 0x397CEDB37FA0E1D2) from execution plan XML in cache - which statistics was used to generate that plan.
This section in XML plan looks like that:
<OptimizerStatsUsage>
    <StatisticsInfo Database="[MyDatabaseName]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[MyTable_1]" 
        Statistics="[IX_MyTable_1_Field1]" ModificationCount="2" 
        SamplingPercent="100" LastUpdate="2024-06-13T13:39:04.41" />
    <StatisticsInfo Database="[MyDatabaseName]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[MyTable_2]" 
        Statistics="[_WA_Sys_00000015_4B4D17CD]" ModificationCount="0" 
        SamplingPercent="100" LastUpdate="2024-06-13T12:06:33.17" />
</OptimizerStatsUsage> 

If it is possible I want information:

Schema
Table
Statistics
ModificationCount
SamplingPercent
LastUpdate


So what is your question? You've told us what you want, but not what you are asking. What is stopping you achieving your goal?

In other words, what have you tried so far, and how has that failed? The site isn't a free code-writing service.

You can use SQL-XQuery for this. .nodes will shred the XML into separate rows, and .value pulls out a single value.
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'
)
SELECT
  [Schema]          = x1.statsinfo.value('@Schema', 'sysname'),
  [Table]           = x1.statsinfo.value('@Table', 'sysname'),
  [Statistics]      = x1.statsinfo.value('@Statistics', 'sysname'),
  ModificationCount = x1.statsinfo.value('@ModificationCount', 'bigint'),
  SamplingPercent   = x1.statsinfo.value('@SamplingPercent', 'float'),
  LastUpdate        = x1.statsinfo.value('@LastUpdate', 'datetime2(7)')
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
CROSS APPLY qp.query_plan.nodes('//OptimizerStatsUsage/StatisticsInfo') x1(statsinfo)
WHERE qs.query_plan_hash = @QueryPlanHash;


I recommend using Powershell.  You can use the cmdlet Invoke-SQLCMD to access the database.  One you retrieve the xml you can use following to parse the xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$input_filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($input_filename)
$OptimizerStatsUsage = $doc.Descendants('OptimizerStatsUsage')[0]

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($statisticsInfo in $OptimizerStatsUsage[0].Elements('StatisticsInfo'))
{
      $schema = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('Schema').Value
      $xTable = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('Table').Value
      $statistics = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('Statistics').Value
      $modificationCount = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('ModificationCount').Value
      $samplingPercent = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('SamplingPercent').Value
      $lastUpdate = $statisticsInfo.Attribute('LastUpdate').Value
      $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
       Schema = $schema.Trim(@('[',']'))
       Table = $xTable.Trim(@('[',']'))
       Statistics = $statistics.Trim(@('[',']'))
       ModificationCount = [int]$modificationCount
       SamplingPercent = [decimal]$samplingPercent
       LastUpdate = [DateTime]::Parse($lastUpdate)
      }
      $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table

Results
Schema            : dbo
Table             : MyTable_1
Statistics        : IX_MyTable_1_Field1
ModificationCount : 2
SamplingPercent   : 100
LastUpdate        : 6/13/2024 1:39:04 PM

Schema            : dbo
Table             : MyTable_2
Statistics        : _WA_Sys_00000015_4B4D17CD
ModificationCount : 0
SamplingPercent   : 100
LastUpdate        : 6/13/2024 12:06:33 PM

You can get a table using
$table | Format-Table
Here is the output
Schema Table     Statistics                ModificationCount SamplingPercent LastUpdate
------ -----     ----------                ----------------- --------------- ----------
dbo    MyTable_1 IX_MyTable_1_Field1                       2             100 6/13/2024 1:39:04 PM
dbo    MyTable_2 _WA_Sys_00000015_4B4D17CD                 0             100 6/13/2024 12:06:33 PM

